# Numpy: advanced slices

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, slice

I need a fast way to find the smallest element among three neighbor elements in a string, and add it to element under the central element. For border elements only two upper elements are checking.

For example I have a numpy array:

```
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I should get this:

```
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I have this code:

```
for h in range(1, matrix.shape[0]):
    matrix[h][0] = min(matrix[h - 1][0], matrix[h - 1][1])
    matrix[h][1:-1] = ...(DONT KNOW, WHAT SHOULD BE HERE!!)
    matrix[h][-1] = min(matrix[h - 1][-2], matrix[h - 1][-1])
```

How can I count it without using more `for` loops because I have too much data and I need to make it fast? `Edit:` David-z, here is my project) [image: Seam carving]

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do this for a whole 2D array with many rows. Do you really need _all_ the values, or just the last row, or just one value in the last row? In the latter case there might be some more specialized algorithm you can use.

Comment: @david-z I work with big images and I count some energy, converting them into YUV. Yes, I need to count every value, to find the smallest value on the last line! It is important to find seam through the whole image which I will delete to resize image in a smart way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.minimum.reduce`:

```
matrix[h][1:-1] = numpy.minimum.reduce([matrix[h-1][0:-2], matrix[h-1][1:-1], matrix[h-1][2:]])
```

For example:

```
>>> matrix = numpy.zeros((2,10))
>>> matrix[0, :] = numpy.random.randint(0,100,10)
>>> h = 1
>>> matrix[h][0] = matrix[h-1][:2].min()
>>> matrix[h][1:-1] = numpy.minimum.reduce([matrix[h-1][0:-2], matrix[h-1][1:-1], matrix[h-1][2:]])
>>> matrix[h][-1] = matrix[h-1][-2:].min()
>>> matrix
array([[ 10.,  40.,  90.,  13.,  21.,  58.,  64.,  56.,  34.,  69.],
       [ 10.,  10.,  13.,  13.,  13.,  21.,  56.,  34.,  34.,  34.]])
```

Comment: Well, I explained not clear enough! Elements, which are situated between border elements should be found, using three neighbors under! For element matrix[h][w] we need to check matrix[h-1][w-1], matrix[h-1][w] and matrix[h-1][w+1]!!

Comment: @Tehada: well, I explained the code not clear enough. It takes the minimum of the three neighboring elements `w-1`, `w` and `w+1`, but as vectors to eliminate another loop.

Comment: thanks a lot! Now it takes only 0.02 seconds instead 1.3 when I used 2 for loops! Now I am thinking about one more improvement: I have a big 2D-table with int values and I'd like to solve this problem without any for loops.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it explicitly for somewhat more clarity with explicit slicing

```
n = 10
x = np.random.randint(0,100,n)
y = np.zeros_like(x,dtype=int)


for ind in range(n):
    if ind == 0:
        lo , hi = None , ind + 2
    elif ind >= n-2:
        lo , hi = ind - 1 , None
    else:
        lo , hi = ind - 1 , ind + 2
    y[ind] = np.min(x[lo:hi])
```

An example output is

```
[21 74 95 96  6 96 78 74  6 92  5 32 72 64 30 13 72 59 19 26]
[21 21 74  6  6  6 74  6  6  5  5  5 32 30 13 13 13 19 19 19]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight variation on `Daniel's` solution:

Start with the row or list of values:

```
In [439]: z=[10,40,90,13,21,58,64,56,34,69]
```

Replicate the 1st and last values; I could do that with concatenate, indexing, or the simple `pad` (internally `pad` is rather complicated because it is so general):

```
In [440]: z1=np.pad(z,(1,1),'edge')
In [441]: z1
Out[441]: array([10, 10, 40, 90, 13, 21, 58, 64, 56, 34, 69, 69])
```

Now the make the 3 row matrix (the core of Daniel's solution):

```
In [443]: [z1[0:-2], z1[1:-1], z1[2:]]
Out[443]: 
[array([10, 10, 40, 90, 13, 21, 58, 64, 56, 34]),
 array([10, 40, 90, 13, 21, 58, 64, 56, 34, 69]),
 array([40, 90, 13, 21, 58, 64, 56, 34, 69, 69])]
```

`np.min` on `axis=0` is the equivalent to the `minimum.reduce`:

```
In [444]: np.min([z1[0:-2], z1[1:-1], z1[2:]],axis=0)
Out[444]: array([10, 10, 13, 13, 13, 21, 56, 34, 34, 34])
```

=========

Extending this to a 2d array:

```
In [454]: y=np.array(z).reshape(2,5)        # same values, reshape
In [455]: y1=np.pad(y,((0,0),(1,1)),'edge')  # 2d pad
In [456]: y1
Out[456]: 
array([[10, 10, 40, 90, 13, 21, 21],
       [58, 58, 64, 56, 34, 69, 69]])
In [457]: Y=np.array([y1[:,0:-2], y1[:,1:-1], y1[:,2:]])
In [458]: Y                            # 3d array
Out[458]: 
array([[[10, 10, 40, 90, 13],
        [58, 58, 64, 56, 34]],

       [[10, 40, 90, 13, 21],
        [58, 64, 56, 34, 69]],

       [[40, 90, 13, 21, 21],
        [64, 56, 34, 69, 69]]])
In [459]: np.min(Y,axis=0)
Out[459]: 
array([[10, 10, 13, 13, 13],
       [58, 56, 34, 34, 34]])
```

===============

An `as_strided` alternative (for advanced numpy users only :))

```
In [462]: np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(z1,shape=(10,3),strides=(4,4)).T
Out[462]: 
array([[10, 10, 40, 90, 13, 21, 58, 64, 56, 34],
       [10, 40, 90, 13, 21, 58, 64, 56, 34, 69],
       [40, 90, 13, 21, 58, 64, 56, 34, 69, 69]])
```

Comment: Well, it is beautiful solution and clear, I will learn this one! But is it fast on big data?